Unlike other sites, why don't we delete most annoying, but harmless, spammer accounts, here?
On most Stack Exchange sites, not only do spammer's posts get deleted, their accounts do, too. One example of this is SuperUser's Spammer Cannery, a chat room I participate in, that is dedicated to reporting spammer accounts, who receive an account deletion effective-immediately.

I am well aware that "offensive" spammers, who spam inappropriate content, do get removed, here. But as far as I've seen, most harmless but annoying ones usually don't.
Is this due to the smaller size of this site, or do we just operate differently in general?
Or have am I wrong altogether? Do most spammers usually get removed and I just haven't been around long enough to realize?

You can't see the ones that have been removed ... Hence, what you're seeing are the ones we've missed. A bit of a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias in your conclusion.

@schroeder ahh, sorry if I am being biased. I was only going off the ones I’ve only being going off the ones I’ve seen, but obviously posts that have been removed before I’ve seen them factor in, as well the fact that I’m still a fairly new user. When you delete a spam post, do you often remove the user at the same time? Or is this classified information?

It's a judgement call and we need to make sure the user gets flagged as a spammer by the system. And sometimes the system deletes posts automatically without deleting the user. Obvious bots get deleted. Non-obvious posters might need guidance. There isn't a one-size-fits-all approach.

As @schroeder says, the vast majority are removed completely. We delete the post and the account at the same time.
You see a tiny fraction that we either have missed, have not yet assessed as definitely spammers, or are probably just misguided folks we hope to steer the correct way.

Thanks for elaborating, it does appear that I’ve fallen into the trap of survivorship bias. I’ll take note when spammers are removed, for future reference.

@security_paranoid to elaborate a little bit more on "missed", spam posts can be deleted by the community with enough flags without mod intervention, and there's no notification to the mod either when something is deleted as spam, so the spammer account can be unnoticed by them.

Rory Alsop, sorry to circle around back to this question, but after realising what Andrew T. said, is there any way to report a spammer who’s post has been deleted by the community, and therefore that you mods have missed? I am not saying this is really necessary, because it isn’t a big deal. I am just wondering.

Absolutely, @security_paranoid - you can flag other posts of theirs. The good thing is that whether it's mods or community that flag as spam, that feeds into charcoal to aid in preventing spam.

Very good point. Because if they only spam once, it doesn’t really matter if their account doesn’t get deleted, and if they are a repeat offender, then surely a mod will eventually see. Cheers.
